# Android Return From Camera Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, camera

In my code when i cancel the image taken by camera...the app crashes and give error that your application has stopped..Please help me how to solve it.All i want that my camera is returned to my application if taken image is cancelled...Here is my code:

```
int take_image=1;

buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


            startActivityForResult(i, take_image);

        }

});




  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




        if (requestCode == take_image) {

             //simple data show for user ease

             Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
             imageView2.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
             }
  if (requestCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
      Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);    
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your log file.

Answer (score 0):

be careful of requestCode and resultCode, they are different. Modify your code:

```
if (requestCode == take_image) {
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        //simple data show for user ease
         Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
         imageView2.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
         setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent); 
    }
}
```